# putting jquery and javascript into external file

Tags: javascript, jquery

A lot of my pages have amll bits of jquery.

Im thinking of putting them into one external file with one `$(document).ready(function() {`

and everything in there.

is this a good/bad idea?

will each page be slower overall if there is more code to execute even if its not relevant to the page? i imagine each line of code in the external script gets executed when the **dom** is ready..? or is my understanding wrong?

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript, by the way; jQuery is not a language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> will each page be slower overall if there is more code to execute even if its not relvamnt to the page?

The external script file may have some overheads for loading, but if you use the script on any number of pages more than one, external is a good idea; it'll be cached and be instant.

> i imagine each line of code in the external script gets executed when the dom is ready..? or is my understanding wrong?

Yes. If you wrap your code in a function as an argument to `$(document).ready()` it gets executed on `DOMContentLoaded`.

Answer (score 1):

If you put all your bits of JS into one page - without calling them as functions- then, yes, they will get executed everytime you include them. It would be better to put the common functions into an external scripts and keep it there. This will increase your code reuse as well as speed up page load because your JS will be cached.

Comment: so sould i keep page sepecific code in the pages? will that be quicker overall than using a cached external script?

Comment: If you can refactor your code then that would be good. Don't make a lot of tiny files only a few lines of JS though. If it's only a couple of lines, leave it on the page. You aren't going to gain much from moving it to a separate file because the browser has to send an extra request to grab the file

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by refactor, or point me at a decent book / tut. I read the same old "make all js external" a lot without any explanation of how to handle the page specific stuff that can not / should not be executed on every page load. Kind of annoying.

Comment: Basically, if the page specific JS is only a few lines simply keep it in the HTML page as you don't gain anything from moving it out. However, if it's a lot of JS, it will be easier for you to modify and maintain if you keep it in any external JS. By refactoring, I mean moving any common utility functions to a different file. If it's a function, it won't get run just by including it and you gain some performance because the page can be cached.